# How to extract param from url in prototype?

Tags: javascript, url, prototypejs

I want to get param from html links.

For example I have following HTML string.

**Example 1:**

```
<div class='mydiv'><a href="/display/2">Link</a></div>    // get 2
```

**Example 2:**

```
<div class='mydiv'><a href="/display/abc">Link</a></div>  // get abc
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code you've written so far, and describe fully what you're having trouble with and where you're stuck.

Comment: I just tried this `$('mydiv').innerHTML` and result is `<a href="/display/2">Link</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/7EGqr/) which demonstrates the required functionality with prototype.

or check below...

```
var links = $$('div.mydiv > a[href]').inject([], function(arr, el) {
    arr.push($A(el.getAttribute('href').split('/')).last()); 
    return arr;  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply treat it as an array and use the `split()` function:

```
var myURL = "/display/2";
var splits = myURL.split("/");

alert(splits[splits .length - 1]);
```

**EDIT**

I misunderstood your original question. I thought you simply needed to know how to extract `2` and `abc` from the href. Since I don't know prototype.js (I'm a jQuery man), here's a pure JS solution:

```
var classElements = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv");
var parsedHrefs = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < classElements.length; i++) {
    var anchorsInDiv = classElements[i].getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(var j = 0; j < anchorsInDiv.length; j++) {
        var splitHref = anchorsInDiv[j].href.split("/");
        parsedHrefs.push(splitHref[splitHref.length - 1]);
    }
}

alert(parsedHrefs);
```

You can view [a working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/H9Qsd/).

**Additional Information**

In case you're interested, here's how it would be done in jQuery:

```
var aryParsedHrefs = new Array();

$(".mydiv").find("a").each(function() {
    var splitHref = $(this).attr("href").split("/");
    aryParsedHrefs.push(splitHref[splitHref.length - 1]);
});

alert(aryParsedHrefs);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/VvNxt/).

Comment: How will  I get `/display/2` from `<div class='mydiv'><a href="/display/2">Link</a></div>` ?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href

Comment: something like: $(".mydiv").find("a").attr("href"); (if you only have 1 a href in your div). It's better to give it a class to select. Btw this is jQuery

Comment: @JamesHill: + thanks for your effort. I got another short answer here in prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Using split function

```
$("a").each(function(){

   var hrefSplit = this.href.split("/");
   if(hrefSplit){
       var asssociatedParam = hrefSplit[ hrefSplit.length -1 ];
    }

});
```

In pure JavaScript

```
arr = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for( var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++){
     var hrefSplit = arr[0].href.split("/");
       if(hrefSplit){
           var asssociatedParam = hrefSplit[ hrefSplit.length -1 ];
        }
}
```